# php include or require echos for no reason

Tags: php, utf-8

i'm working on a website. I have a file in php and I want to include it. The file contains a big array, **nothing** else.

When I tried to include it, the page functioned normally but I needed to convert my included file from ANSI to UTF8. After converting (notepad++) i get a big space at the top of the screen. Using firebug I was able to figure out that when I include the UTF8 encoded version of the file, it echos break lines... As you would assume, that is the kind of behaviour i did not expect. How to convert the file so that it does not echo itself for no reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert it to **UTF-8 without BOM**.

Make sure your file looks like this (there is nothing before `<?php`):

```
<?php
    $array=array(
         /* elements */
    );
```

Comment: Try to remove any and all whitespace too, just to be safe.

Comment: this actually did the trick... 2 hours of my life gone becouse of this.. :)

Comment: @Andrej Happy to save your life :). Just remember to always use UTF-8 without BOM and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

put the

```
 <?php
```

open tag at the very beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

And do not include a `?>` tag at the end of your file, if it only contains PHP code.